# Angular 2: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback." when calling JSONP

Tags: angular

I try to call Jsonp request:

```
getData() {   
  const queryParam = "?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK";   
  return this.jsonp.get('http://localhost:3000/data/bar-chart-data' + queryParam)    
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data.json()),
  err => console.log(err)); 
}
```

This is the url setting from express.js

```
app.get('/data/bar-chart-data', function (req, res) { 
   res.json({"foo": "bar"}); 
})
```

But it keeps throwing this error:

> Response_body: "JSONP injected script did not invoke callback."
>   headers: Headersok: true status: 200' statusText: "Ok" type: 3url:
>   "http://localhost:3000/data/bar-chart-data
>   callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished"

Comment: Hi, did you find a resolution to this problem? I am facing the same issue